# weird nesting in xml

Tags: xml

this seems to be a valid xml file and i was able to import it into dropdownlist, but i don't understand the funny nesting. :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Countries>
  <Country>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Nepal</Name>
  </Country>
  <Country>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>India</Name>
    <Country>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Name>China</Name>
    </Country>
    <Country>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <Name>Bhutan</Name>
    </Country>
    <Country>
      <ID>5</ID>
      <Name>USA</Name>
    </Country>
  </Country>
</Countries>
```

why is there a closing second to last line? what is it closing? and why is india not closed?

Comment: The extra closing tag belongs with India.  Was this a trick question, see if I was still awake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your file thinks China, Bhutan, and USA are children of India.  India is, in fact, closed by the last country end tag.  It is technically an "acceptable" (actual term for this is *well-formed*) XML file, but sanity checks say it makes no sense.  File probably should look like this:

```
<Countries>
<Country>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Name>Nepal</Name>
</Country>
<Country>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Name>India</Name>
</Country>
<Country>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <Name>China</Name>
</Country>
<Country>
  <ID>4</ID>
  <Name>Bhutan</Name>
</Country>
<Country>
  <ID>5</ID>
  <Name>USA</Name>
</Country>
</Countries>
```

Comment: Indeed, it's well-formed, but would not be valid under a sensible schema.  Whether the schema /is/ sensible is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Its well formed in theory, but doesnt look well formed to me, by the pattern i see. Most likely just a typo. Or it was generated there is a bug in the code that does the generation.

Comment: yes i know it is well formed, that is what i said, read it. i said the patten makes is look weird and makes it not look well formed. thanks for the negative on this, most undeserved.